# How to change color of checkbox label while toggling checked/unchecked state on click

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I'm trying to change the font color and background color of my checkbox label when I check or uncheck. I found a javascript solution on this site but haven't been able to make the code to work. Here is what I've tried so far. Right now it is attaching the "highlight" class to the parent div and I only want the label to change. Thanks for your time.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="option one" value="orange"><label for="1" class="highlight">Orange</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="option two" value="apple"><label for="1" class="highlight">Apple</label>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$( '.checkboxes' ).on( 'click', 'input:checkbox', function () {
    $( this ).parent().toggleClass( 'highlight', this.checked );
}); // end checkbox style​
```

**CSS**:

```css
.checkboxes label {
    font-family:Open Sans Italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.highlight {
    font-family:Open Sans Italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    background: #86b3c1;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label comes after the checkbox, your code seems to be meant for a label that is wrapping the checkbox, like so:

```
<label for="1" class="highlight">Orange
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="option one" value="orange">
</label>
```

Change the html or change the JS to target the next element and not the closest parent element:

```
$( '.checkboxes' ).on( 'click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
    $( this ).next('label').toggleClass( 'highlight', this.checked );
});
```

Also, your CSS is faulty, and targeting the label directly will take presedence over the highlight class, so it will never change color even if the class is applied.

Here's a fiddle, I've fixed it by being more specific when targeting the highligth class:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UdN7D/2/)

And Raminson is correct, you should target the checkbox with brackets and type="".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error! It changed the JS. However it looks like my css property of .checkboxes label {} is overriding the .highlight class so the label is not changing. How could I fix that?

Comment: @Ansh - I've already answered that, but I edited the answer and the fiddle to show how.

Comment: @Ansh you can change the css selector from `.highlight` to `label.highlight`.

Comment: thanks! that works. thanks for pointing out the css flaw as well. i will fix that first to make this work correctly

Answer (score 9):

You can do it using just CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label { /* styles that get changed */ }
```

demo http://dabblet.com/gist/3157721

Also, while producing the demo I've noticed a couple of issues:

- `id="option one"` - the id must be only one and you cannot have spaces
- the value of the `for` attribute of the `label` should be the `id` (not `name`) of the corresponding `input`; this also lets you check/ uncheck the checkbox by clicking on the label and not on the checkbox itself

Comment: thanks again! the demo is really helpful. i've corrected the `for` and the id.

Answer (score 2):

`closest()` does not find a closest element to the selected element. it finds the closest parent, you can use `next()` method, try the following:

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

```
$('.checkboxes').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
     $(this).next('label').toggleClass('highlight', this.checked);
});
```

*please note that `:checkbox` selector is [`deprecated`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/).*

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for pointing out the correct method of targeting the checkbox.