# How to change label color of disabled checkbox in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, css, checkbox, controls

How to change disabled checkbox label of asp controls through CSS. Check disabled but the label colour is not changing even i tried through CSS, so any clue or hint with CSS?

Comment: You can Use Jquery addclass property

Comment: how do you disable your checkbox? through attribute enabled=false or disabled="yes" ?in case of later, disabled controls don't show color on IE

Comment: Thanks Ramesh Rajendran & Manish Mishra, my issue resolved by @Anh Tú answer... Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use plus (+) sign to get adjacent element (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label{ font-weight: bold; }

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label
{
     color:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: we can't access disabled property in checkbox. He want to change label color of when enabled checkbox only.So your both solution is not worked .

Answer (score 0):

Try this below way

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check-with-label" />
  <label class="label-for-check">My Label</label>
<div>


.check-with-label:Enabled + .label-for-check {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:red;
}
```

See this [checked design](http://jsbin.com/oqeteh/11/edit)

More discussions

[How to change color of checkbox label while toggling checked/unchecked state on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596837/how-to-change-color-of-checkbox-label-while-toggling-checked-unchecked-state-on)

[Change label when checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833982/change-label-when-checkbox-is-checked)

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh, problem is solve with:

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label{ font-weight: bold; }  
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label
{
     color:#ccc;
}
plus (+) sign to get adjacent element (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
ListItem li = new ListItem("Richard Byrd", "11");
li.Selected = false;
li.Attributes.Add("Style", "color: red;");
CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(li);
```

Or you can use like this as label is rendered in `td` so the below can be a solution

Style.css

```
.chkboxlist td 
{
    color:red;
}
```

Page.aspx

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkboxlist1" runat="server" CssClass="chkboxlist" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Shekhar, problem is solve with: input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label{ font-weight: bold; } input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label { color:#ccc; } plus (+) sign to get adjacent element (w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)